# visual studio 2017 community создаёт проект БЕСКОНЕЧНО

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Начал создавать проект в vs на C#, но проект создаётся бесконечно. Ждал создания проекта часов 8, но ничего не создалось.

Comment: Попробуйте переустановить vs

Comment: переустановка не помогает

Comment: Ну тогда проблемы в системе. У всех создаётся у вас не. Значит чего-то не хватает

Comment: Я понял, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Выберите другой каталог для проекта, проект создается не более 30 секунд, ждать 8 часов нет необходимости. И поставьте [VS 2019 Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/), она бесплатная, для обучения - то что нужно. Не вижу смысла использовать старую.

Comment: другой каталог не помог